# Blog site with existing domain name

Tags: blog, hosting, domain-name

I would like to have a blog site, though I have created my own by writing the code. Huhhh... hosting cost is killing me. I have my domain name with me and I just wanted to get the blog where I can use my unused domain name.

My blog will me 80% technical (i.e. I will show peices of code and downloadable content to my user). Which blog will be useful for me. I just don't want my URL look like `http://mysite.hosterName.com`

I want it like this `http://www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress, Blogger, Posterous & Tumblr - all provide hosting with custom domains. I believe WordPress charges extra for custom domains, while Blogger, Posterous & Tumblr do not.

Comment: Blogger is free at least: http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1233381

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise thanks, updated. Thought it was paid.

Comment: Can confirm Blogger is free and allows (assuming you have access to your domain's DNS settings) allows anysubdomain.yourdomain.com, I currently have mine set up as blog.mydomain.com for free

Comment: @GAThrawn Thanks, +1. Is there any way I can be with my domain like www.mydomain.com rather than blog.mydomain.com or blogger.mydomain.com ?

Comment: @Chris you can point blogger at any valid servername.yourdomain.com even www. (as long as you don't already have anything on www. that you want to keep), see http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1233381

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of whatever blog service as you wish and force the blog to run inside of a frame with the next code in an html file, this way you can use a folder in your main public_html site and make a kind of a redirection to the blogging service as you wish.

The code would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 
<html>
<head> 
  <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"> 
  <title>Place here your site's name</title> 
</head> 

<frameset title="Player" border="0" frameborder="no" rows="*" onload="doLoad()" onunload="doUnload()"> 
<frame title="Content" noresize="noresize" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://placeheretheblogname.blogspot.com" name="course_frame" scrolling="auto"> 
</frameset> 

</html>
```

The previous code will work just if the blogging service that you are using allows you to run the blog inside of a frame. Of which I have noticed that Blogger (.blogspot.com) and Wordpress will allow you. This trick will work even for static or dynamic pages.

To see the code in action click the next link: http://geppettvs.servehttp.com/blog

When you see inside of the code (with development tools or extensions) you will see the code redirecting to my own hosting service in which I have placed the blog, which is -indeed- other than the link you have clicked.

Good luck!

P.S. This trick will allow you to drop a kind of link that looks like: http://www.yourdomain.com/blog <== change "blog" for whatever you name the blog's folder.

Answer (score -1):

Blogger allows this. You will just need to redirect your domain DNS settings to point to Google servers.

For detailed instructions, check out http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs